# iOS15 How can I test the App Icon in Xcode 13?

Tags: ios15, xcode13

In the session [Get ready to optimize your App Store product page](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10295) show:

> And remember, to test a variation of your app icon, you'll need to include the icon assets in the binary of your app version that is currently live.

How should I create different app icons in Xcode 13, or is there any related documentation link? thanks~

- [How do you properly add multiple App Icons inside Xcode for Product Page Optimization Tests?| Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696491)
- [How to test a variation of your app… | Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685321)

Answer (score 32):

You are right that Apple doesn't give too many details about it. You need to set up an alternate app icon in your binary. Here's a step by step tutorial on how to do it:

1. Create your app icon creatives (1024px x 1024px)
2. Set your app icon(s) in XCode as another App Icon in the Asset Catalog, fill in all the relevant sizes
   [image: Add Icon to XCode]
3. Since Xcode 13, Asset Catalog supports Alternate App Icons and there’s a corresponding build setting we need to change to the target’s Build Settings:
   [image: Build Settings]
4. Change the **Include All App Icon Asset** to Yes
5. Add the App Icon Set you added in #2 to the **Alternate App Icon Sets** setting, you can add more than one.
6. Change the **Primary App Icon Set Name** to the default app icon if needed
7. You need to upload your new build to review.
8. Only **after** your new build has been approved and your app is in Ready For Sale state, you may find your alternate app icons in the Product Page Optimization under the App Icon tab
   [image: App Icon tab]

Comment: Can I keep the same app icon for 1 or more tests. I want to only experiment with the app store screenshots and don't want different app icon versions

Comment: You can keep the same icon for other tests as well. If you don't need to test the app icon, you can ignore this tutorial above and just upload your screenshots to the Apple Page Optimization.

Comment: Does the app icon A/B test affect the installed app icon?

Comment: @IgorMakarov, yes.

Comment: I am using xcode 13.4 . I don't see "Alternate App icons set" in Asset Catalog compiler

Comment: Apple does not accept this way anymore... They say "allow users to change app icon in your app if you add alternate app icons. Otherwise, we don't accept your app submission. 2nd way: You can remove alternate app icons if you want us to approve your app"

Comment: I mean you should add a code solution also to allow users to change app icon in the app or you should provide another solution(if it exists) when this solution is out-dated for now...

Comment: Im on Xcode 14.2 and I don't have "Alternate App icons set" in target's build settings. Do we not need to specify it anymore?